# Simple Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is a super simple question I imagine, but I am creating a macro and several of the lines are a mile long. Is there a way to wrap the text so I can view the one long line of text as 2 separate lines?

Comment: What is your IDE?
You could alway do it manually by adding an underscore (_) and then enter: this will make sure that the compiler treats it as a single line.

Comment: >What is your IDE? Probably Excel? ;)

Comment: Yes, it is in Excel (hence the title of the question). But the underscore thing is not working

Comment: Consider breaking up the macro into simpler statements and store values in intermediate variables. You are doing it wrong if you try to do everything into one line. I am curious to see the code now.

Answer (score 3):

Insert a **space character,** an **underscore character** and a **hard return** in the middle of the line.  For example:

```
Sub dural()
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
End Sub
```

becomes:

```
Sub dural()
Dim a As String, _
b As String, _
c As String
End Sub
```